# can a one-element set $L$ have a top and bottom element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A top element $u_2$ satisfies $a\leq u_2$ for all $a$ in $L$; similarly, a bottom element $u_1$ satisfies $u_1\leq a$ for all $a$ in $L$. If we have a one element subset, then $u_1=u_1$, so $u_1$ is both a top and bottom element. True?

Comment: What if anything are you uncertain about?

Comment: Can a one-element subset have a top and bottom element? It doesn't make sense to me, because I thought top and bottom elements had to be unique, such that a1 =/= a2 if a1 is a bottom element and a2 is a top element.

Comment: Does the one element satisfy the requirements? That is, is $a \le a$?

Comment: Well, the top and bottom elements *are* unique, they simply happen to coincide. There is still a unique top element and a unique bottom element, they just happen to be the same. In your definition, it doesn't appear that it is required that $u_1$ and $u_2$ be distinct, but if that is the case, then indeed, the one element set wouldn't be able to have both a top and bottom element.
Also, when you say $u_1 = u_1$, do you really mean $u_1 = u_2$?

Comment: if u1 = u2, and u1 and u2 are the only elements in the set, then that implies there is a singleton set u1 with u1 as its top and bottom element. correct?

(sorry for the wordiness - just a student hopelessly lost in class)

Answer (score 0):

I've often seen these "top elements" referred to as suprema, and the "bottom elements" as infima, so I'll use that terminology going forward. We'll let $\le$ denote the partial ordering going forward.

- An element $a \in S$ is a supremum if $s \le a$ for every $s \in S$.
- An element $b \in S$ is an infimum if $a \le s$ for every $s \in S$.

Note that we do not use "for every $s \in S \setminus \{a\}$" (or $S\setminus \{b\}$) here -- that is, it has to hold for every element of $S$, including the supremum/infimum itself! (We also note, somewhat more subtly, there is no tenet that says these two need be distinct elements.)

In that light, it of course makes sense that you could have a singleton set $L := \{a\}$ with both a supremum and infimum; you need only give it the proper partial ordering $\le$ (which would likely be more difficult to *not* do considering there's only one element in $L$).

For instance, let $\le$ be, quite literally, the "less than or equal to" relation, with $a$ some real number. Then $a \le \ell$ for all $\ell \in L$ (namely $a \le a$), so $a$ is an infimum of the set. Likewise, $\ell \le a$ for all $\ell \in L$ (namely $a \le a$), so $a$ is also a supremum of the set. So as a result, $\inf(L) = \sup(L) = a$. While somewhat silly to think about, this is totally fine and mostly just a consequence of working with a really simple example.